# Advice for senior thesis

Tags: options, futures, finance-mathematics

I'd like to get my degree in mathematical finance, or eventually in quantitative finance. Could you give me some (original) ideas, maybe transversal between the two, on which to focus my thesis?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My advice would be to find a good advisor and get a thesis topic from him. There are just too many unknowns here: faculty area of research, data sets you have access to, etc Besides, by working with someone at the department you'll get exposed to the area of research he's an expert in, and will be able to work on something potentially more impactful.

Comment: @LazyCat Thanks for your answer. Clearly I'll talk with my rapporteur; it was just to get some ideas before heading into his office.

Comment: In your mind, what's the difference between Mathematical Finance and Quantitative Finance? (Btw, I don't believe you are L'Ottavo Re di Roma :). )

Comment: @ir7 No difference: mathematical finance provides a mathematical justification of how financial instruments work, and quantitative finance uses these results to calculate the value of strategies, instruments etc. But the question is: why this question?

Comment: This Applied Math area goes by many names. You say 'no difference', but then you go on stating one is 'theory' while the other is 'application'. A good program should cover both sides fairly. This wiki entry can help (note also the mentioning of computational finance and financial engineering): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_finance#:~:text=Mathematical%20finance%2C%20also%20known%20as,mathematical%20modeling%20of%20financial%20markets.

Comment: @ir7  It's easier to explain the difference with books: for mathematical finance I studied on "Calcolo stocastico per la finanza - Andrea Pascucci"; for quantitative finance "Options, futures and other derivatives - John C. Hull".

Comment: @ir7 And in fact the goal is to find a transversal (and original) argument for this math area.